# How to pass data from MainActivity to multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

My project looks something like this:

1. MainActivity
2. SelectActivity
3. MapActivity

I have data on my MainActivity that i need to send to MapActivity, the problem is that i can not go straight to MapActivity without have selected an item from my SelectActivity.

I was doing the following:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapSelectActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putDouble("Lon",longitude);
    b.putDouble("Lat",latitude);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
```

But the app just started crashing due to the thing i mention earlier that i can not go into the activity without have been selected something from the SelectActivity.

Anythought on how can I make this?.
I hope i've made myself clear.
Thank you in advace for your help.

Comment: i dont have a database, i just want to send two _double_, it will work right?

Comment: how you want to navigate between the three activities? Is it from MainActivity to SelectActivity and then SelectActivity  from to MapActivity right ?

Comment: Yes that is how i navigate.

Answer (score 1):

As you navigate from `MainActivity` to `SelectActivity` and then from `SelectActivity` to `MapActivity`

And you want to send data from `MainActivity` to `MapActivity`, then you can send this data in two stages:

- **Stage 1:** from `MainActivity` to `SelectActivity`
- **Stage 2:** from `SelectActivity` to `MapActivity`

In MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putDouble("Lon",longitude);
b.putDouble("Lat",latitude);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

In SelectActivity:

```
// get the bundle sent from MainActivity to SelectActivity
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
Intent intent = new Intent(SelectActivity.this, MapActivity.class);

// add more data to bundle from the SelectActivity
// b.addXX();

intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

In MapActivity:

```
// get the bundle sent from SelectActivity to MapActivity
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
b.getDouble("Lon");
b.getDouble("Lat");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now i have a problem that if i make that the app chrashes.

Comment: @AlejandroSantamaría can you update the question with the crash report if it's related to the same question. or you can open a new question with that to keep each question has a certain scope of issues.

Comment: @AlejandroSantamaría If you found that kind of helpful, please accept the answer, that will help make people who have the same question in the future.